# How to use "as const" on dynamically generated objects in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

As the title suggests I've been trying every possible way and solution that I could find online to use "as const" on a dynamic object but no luck whatsoever so I would greatly appreciate any help.

What I'm trying to achieve is generating an object `THEME_NAME_LIST` of the keys used in another object `THEME`, so that I don't have to manually maintain the `THEME_NAME_LIST` object every time some supposedly new key gets to the `THEME` object.

I've been easily able to generate const types from my object up until this point only on statically typed objects like this;

```
export const THEME_NAME_LIST = {
    DARK: 'dark',
    LIGHT: 'light',
} as const;


const THEME_ARRAY = Object.values(THEME_NAME_LIST);
export type ThemeType = typeof THEME_ARRAY[number];
```

And when I hover over the`THEME_NAME_LIST.LIGHT`, the IDE shows the following message;

> (property) LIGHT: "light"

Now everything up until this point works great!
However, when I change `THEME_NAME_LIST` to the example below, the `THEME_NAME_LIST` breaks!

```
const THEME = {
    // ...
    DARK: {
        // ...
    },
    LIGHT: {
        // ...
    },
    // ...
};

export const THEME_NAME_LIST = {} as const;
Object.keys(THEME).forEach((key) => {
    const THEME_NAME = key.toUpperCase();
    THEME_NAME_LIST[THEME_NAME] = key.toLowerCase();
});
```

So when I hover `THEME_NAME_LIST.LIGHT`, the IDE prompts the following message;

> Property `LIGHT` does not exist on type `{}`

Is anybody able to tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: ① Screenshots of IDEs are unfortunately not appropriate here. [Please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218) ② `as const` means "this value is going to stay essentially unchanged for its lifetime, so it's safe to infer very specific types for all its properties and subproperties".  Modifying a value that's been `const`-asserted is therefore probably a mistake.  You can't `as const` after the fact.  That's what's "wrong" but it's hard to say what "right" should be.

Comment: ③ If your use case is represented by your example code, then I'd say you should spend effort on having the compiler compute the final type of that variable rather than trying to worry about having it understand how it's built up.  As shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N95o3N). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thank you, updated the screenshots. Good shout will create examples in the playground you mentioned.

Comment:  I'm afraid there has been a communication problem. I was saying that screenshots are not helpful for [the reasons listed here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218).  At least you should include any textual information as plaintext in addition to the screenshots.  I will disengage unless this is done.  Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, my bad! The IDE doesn't output anything other than what the screenshots show! But your playground link was what I exactly looking for! So thanks and kudos to you
Do you mind posting that comment of yours as the answer, please?

Comment: I would, but I would really appreciate it if you could either remove the screenshots if they're not needed to understand the problem, or type up the relevant portions of it as plain text so that unsighted individuals are not unnecessarily excluded.  I would do it, but without your IDE in front of me it would involve a lot more work than it would for you to copy and paste.

Comment: Or whatever I see another answer here has essentially written this up while I've been asking about it. Oh well!

Comment: Replaced the screenshots  Yes I noticed, but thanks for your help really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const` assertions are not meant for dynamic objects. It tells the compiler your object is readonly. Your above code [gives an error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAKgCQKIFkkwLwwN4CgYEwD0RMAdBfoQCICCASgNIBcOVhhJ5lHAvgDTsYAGQCSAcQRxWeDhy4UyQgUIWVeAbly4ApgA8ADiABOsUJFiJUSAPoA5WmhtiAynEw5eMAIYQY56C0AeQAjACsdYCgyAGsdAE8IAAorNABKMgAzEyRvYAALJKS4+LTMAD42DgDLZCcHNA8SsigQAFUDAx1jAGFfHSS0rQ5U2wbbVzgAbVH7RyQAXSaElpBhEAB3br6IAaHcXn2gA) when you try to manipulate the object.

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.(7053)
```

Instead of applying `const` to the object you're trying to create, apply the `const` assertion on your original object, and derive types from there. I would suggest creating a mapped type like so:

```js
type ThemeNameList = {
  [ThemeName in keyof typeof THEME as Uppercase<ThemeName>]: Lowercase<ThemeName>;
};
```

Note that functions like `Object.keys` won't help preserve string literals. You can place assertions at any point in time, but my suggestion would be to only apply the `ThemeNameList` as an assertion to your new object right before you export.

```js
const _THEME_NAME_LIST: Record<string, unknown> = {};
Object.keys(THEME).forEach((key) => {
  const THEME_NAME = key.toUpperCase();
  _THEME_NAME_LIST[THEME_NAME] = key.toLowerCase();
});

export const THEME_NAME_LIST = _THEME_NAME_LIST as ThemeNameList;
```